# Why can't python parse this json string into a dictionary?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

This is the string I'm trying to parse into a dictionary variable in python 3.8:

`str = '{"asdasd": {"username": "asdsad", "filename": "asdsad", "password": "asdsa", "accounts": "11", "headless": True}}'`

and when I run:

```
import json
json.loads(str)
```

This is the error which is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    json.loads(str)
  File "C:\Users\kaspe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\kaspe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\kaspe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 108 (char 107)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the future, first step is to try your JSON in a validation tool, there are plenty of them online (eg. jsonlint.com). It will save you a lot of head banging.

Comment: @Lars Mohammed can you please mark the answer as accepted if this solved your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your str variable doesn't contains a valid JSON. 
It should have been

```
str = '{"asdasd": {"username": "asdsad", "filename": "asdsad", "password": "asdsa", "accounts": "11", "headless": true}}'
```

In JSON, boolean is represented as true/false and in Python as True/False.

Comment: One way you can find out what the issue is is the error output tells you its char 107 of the string.  `str[107]` is `T`, of `True` which as this answer state, is not valid JSON